# How to delete two TreeNode at same time

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I have a TreeView and I want to remove 2 nodes of it at the same time.

```
node.Remove();
```

This will delete the node, but after this code the next node will automatically selected. Is there a way to prevent that? Or better soloution for me will be deleting the next node right after its pervious node is deleted.

You may ask why. In my program every pair of nodes are necessery for doing something. so If I delete one of them, TreeView control will jump to next member of that pair and because the last one is deleted, all my codes goes wrong since it can not find that node anymore.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: why not delete the second (not selected one) first?

Comment: how can I delete the node which is right after the selected node? is there any indexing that can help? I would like to do something like node[-1].Remove() !!

Comment: see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.aspx

without seeing how you declare and use treeview I cannot help more...

Comment: Have you tried `node.FirstNode.Remove()`

Comment: Why not have another node object point to the next node, then delete your current node, and then delete the next node.

Comment: Yes but my problem is I dont want the TreeView control select any node after a node is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was lucky...My node texts are ending in "_1"and "_2" for each pair of nodes so I came up with this soloution:

```
            if (fileText.EndsWith("_1"))
            {
                selectedFile.NextNode.Remove();
                selectedFile.Remove();
            }
            else
            {
                selectedFile.PrevNode.Remove();
                selectedFile.Remove();
            }
```

Comment: if it wasn't this way you could have used ex. parentNode.Nodes.indexOf(selectedNode);//possibly with %2

Answer (score 1):

With simple tree view and a simple context menu this works for me

```
if (tvwACH.SelectedNode.Text == "Child")
{
  tvwACH.SelectedNode.NextNode.Remove();
  tvwACH.SelectedNode.Remove();
}
```